How to randomly construct a long subgroup chain for $S_n$
Description of the problem
My task is to build an optimal method that randomly constructs a proper subgroup for a given $G \leq S_n$. Here the term "random" is applied loosely and there is no restriction on the distribution. The objective is to then randomly construct a subgroup chain by applying the method recursively. The only restriction is that we prefer longer subgroup chains. Unfortunately I lack any further context and I'm simply trying to understand this problem. All I can say is that this result will somehow be used in a symmetric-key cryptography method.
I'd gladly appreciate any (critical) input and any suggestions and observations. Also, I'd appreciate if you specified any books and papers that would be helpful with this problem. Thanks in advance!
Simple attempts and observations
Let $S$ be a strong generating set of $G \leq S_n$. There are different ways to randomly select a proper subgroup of $G$. For example

Enlist all the proper subgroups of $G$ and choose one randomly
Randomly remove elements from $S$ until the corresponding subset will generate a proper subgroup of $G$.

The remaining problem is the length of the chain of subgroups. Note: the term "long" is also applied loosely here. The general preference is that I want the length of the subgroup chain be bigger than a constant $k$, e.g. $k=10$ for a reasonably big $n$. Nonetheless, I focused on making the subgroup chain as long as possible, rather than longer than $k$.
What solution is acceptable
My understanding of computational group theory is vague. For what it's worth a solution to this problem is considered acceptable if

it involves some sort of randomness in the way it selects the proper subgroups and is not easy to brute-force
The resulting subgroup chain is long enough
The complexity of the method is in reasonable limits.

Useful references and papers

@JeanMarie's useful reference (Cameron, Andrews: Chains of semigroups)
Denote with $l(G)$ the length of longest chain of subgroups in $G \leq S_n$.


(1.1) Theorem: $l(S_n) = \lceil \frac{3n}{2} \rceil - b(n) - 1$ where $b(n)$ is the number of ones in the base 2 representation of $n$.

I failed to understand what is going on in the following:

(1.2) The $b(n)$ suggests how to find a longest chain:

If $n = 2^{a_1} + ... + 2^{a_r}$, where the $a_i$ are distinct and $r=b(n)$, then descend to $S_{2^{a_1}} \times ... \times S_{2^{a_r}}$ in $r-1$ steps
$S_{2^a} > S_{2^{a-1}} \wr S_2 > S_{2^{a-1}} \times S_{2^{a-1}}$ for $a>1$
Then do the bookkeeping.


Additional useful information:

(1.3) The Classification of Finite Simple Groups is needed to show
that there is no longer chain; its use could probably be avoided. For some $n$ (for example $7$ and $15$) there are other chains of the
same length.


(1.4) A trivial observation: by Lagrange’s Theorem, $l(G)$ does not
exceed the number of prime divisors of (G:1) (counted with
multiplicity).

Note: the number of prime divisors of a number $n$ is also known as prime Omega function - $\Omega(n)$.

(1.5) A set of elements of a group is independent if no element lies in the subgroup generated by the others.


(1.6) Theorem: An independent set in $S_n$ has size at most $n-1$, with equality iff it generates the group.


Cameron, Cara: Independent generating sets and geometries for symmetric groups


(2.1) Let $S = (s_i, i \in I)$ be a generating set of group $G$. For $J \subseteq I$ let $G_J = \langle s_i: i \notin J \rangle$. $G_i \equiv G_{\{i\}}$. $S$ is independent if $\forall i \in I, s_i \notin G_i$. It is strongly independent if, in addition, $\forall J,K \subseteq I G_J \cap G_K = G_{J \cup K}$

Note from Julius Whiston: Maximal Independent Generating Sets of the
Symmetric Group:

(2.2*) It is immediately evident that the set of transpositions $\{(12),(23),...,(n-1n)\}$ forms an independent generating set.


(2.3) A family of elements which generates $G$ is independent iff it is a minimal generating set.


(2.4) Theorem: Let $S$ be an independent generating set for $S_n$ of size $n-1$, where $n \geq 7$. Then $S$ is strongly independent.

Observations
I have followed two different approaches. I'll describe them below.
Approach 1.

By having an independent generating set $S$ for $S_n$, it is easy to construct a chain of subgroups. By (2.3) $S$ is also a minimal generating set for $S_n$. This means, that $\forall s \in S, \langle S \backslash \{s\} \rangle < \langle S \rangle$. By removing one random element at each step, a chain of subgroups is obtained.
A strongly independent generating set is a good candidate for random subgroup selection thanks to its definition. Moreover, by (2.4) any independent generating set with size $n \geq 7$ is strongly independent and with (2.2*) we have an example of an independent generating set.

Approach 2.
In this approach I'm using the observation (1.4), that is $l(G) \leq \Omega(G:1)$. This observation gives us the following necessary condition for a certain length $k$ of a subgroup chain starting from $G$ be reachable: $\Omega(G:1) \geq k$. By taking this condition into account during subgroup selection, and by choosing subgroups for which $\Omega(G:1)$ is as big as possible, it is plausible too assume that the generated subgroup chain could be of desired length.

@JeanMarie thanks, I have added a big update to the post including your reference

Alas, I am not versed enough in group theory to be able to answer your questions, but something came to my mind : why don't you consider Galois theory : to a chain of groups corresponds a chain of fields extensions, and, rather often, it is valuable to "jump" from one chain to the other ...

@JeanMarie interesting, could you please suggest me a reference or a book? The ones I found don't seem to talk much about subgroup chains other than proving general theorems for solvable groups.

https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ft.html and, if you use SAGE (online as I do) https://antonleykin.math.gatech.edu/math6122spr12/SAGE/Galois%20groups%20--%20Sage.html

@JeanMarie hi I have a question. Did I understand it well that, if say $f_m(x) = (x-a_1)...(x-a_m)$, where $a_i$ are all simple roots and $G_f$ denotes the Galois group for given $f$, then $S_m \geq G_{f_m} > G_{f_{m-1}} > \dotso > G_{f_1} > {e}$?

Here $\geq$ in the sense of isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_m$

There is no such general result with strict inclusions because it depends for each $p$ if $a_p$ can be expressed in an algebraic way as a function of the previous $a_k$.
